# The data could not be read because it isn't in the correct format

Tags: php, swift, afnetworking

Ok after much searching I don't know what is going on with this, because I thought I fixed when I replaced the keys and it was working. However it is not working anymore and I did not change anything. Don't report for duplicate please none of the questions have been answered.

```
    let URL = "http://localhost/donate/payment.php"
    let params: Dictionary<String,AnyObject> = ["stripeToken": token.tokenId,
        "amount": Int(self.amountTextField.text!)!,
        "currency": "usd",
        "description": self.emailTextField.text!]



    let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = NSSet(array: ["text/plain", "text/html", "application/json"]) as! Set<String>

    manager.PATCH(URL, parameters: params, success: { (operation, responseObject) -> Void in
        guard let response = responseObject as? [String: String] else {
            print("failed")
            return
        } 
        }) { (operation, error) -> Void in

            self.handleError(error)
           }
```

Here is my php code that I got from appcoda (I have never coded in PHP)

```
    <?php
        require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("key");
        $token =  $_POST['stripeToken'];
        $amount = $_POST['amount'];
        $currency = $_POST['currency'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];
            try {
            $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(

            "amount" => $amount*100, // Convert amount in cents to dollar
            "currency" => $currency,
            "source" => $token,
            "description" => $description)
            );

        // Check that it was paid:
        if ($charge->paid == true) {
            $response = array( 'status'=> 'Success', 'message'=>'Payment has been charged!!' );
        } else { // Charge was not paid!
            $response = array( 'status'=> 'Failure', 'message'=>'Your payment could NOT be processed because the payment system rejected the transaction. You can try again or use another card.' );
     }
      header('Content-Type: application/json');
      echo json_encode($response);

     } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
      // The card has been declined
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: why you are using `PATCH` method use `POST` instead

Comment: Post is deprecated for iOS 9

Comment: @HamzaAnsari I guess that was the problem. You want to post it as an answer so I can select it as the correct answer. If you could also explain why Patch is not the right method that would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **PATCH** method is the used if you're updating an existing resource.

Whereas

> **POST** submits data to be processed (e.g., from an HTML form) to the identified resource. The data is included in the body of the request.
>   This may result in the creation of a new resource or the updates of
>   existing resources or both.

And in your php file you are using `POST` method to get the parameters you passed through the request whereas you were using `PATCH` method to pass the parametes and thats the reason why your server was returning error in respnonse